# How to get data from REST API to Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, rest, restful-url

I need a way to read/get data from a REST API to insert it into a table in Oracle DB.
I've been searching for it but I've only found the opposite case.

I'm using PL/SQL Developer & Postman
Do i need another software ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the data in a JSON format? I would suggest starting with the `UTL_HTTP` package.

Comment: yes, it comes in JSON format

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use UTL_HTTP, you can do something as simple as an INSERT ... SELECT ...

```
INSERT INTO my_table(response_data)
  SELECT utl_http.request('http://service.url.com')
  FROM   dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to go is with [Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS)](https://oracle.com/rest).

It's a mid-tier Java application (or servlet with Tomcat/WebLogic) that takes HTTP(S) requests and marshalls that to the Oracle Database.

It handles GETs, PUTs, POSTs, & DELETEs so you can definitely use it to INSERT one or more rows to a TABLE. And it can do that via a SQL statement, or an existing PLSQL API.

[I talk more about this here.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/oracle-rest-data-services-ords/)

Here's a REST Service that let's you POST a new record to a TABLE, including a BLOB (file).

This technology is included with your Oracle Database license at no additional cost.

[image]